# facebook permanent/longterm access key for python project

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I've been developing a python program with the fbconsole that grabs a lot of data from facebook over time and i would like to not have to refresh this access key every two hours. Obviously I have  googled a lot and searched stackoverflow but im still really confused. Is there like a 60 day access token? I have seen some people talk about getting an app id and secret but this is not an app on facebook. Anyways, I would appreciate it if someone could break it up for me and clear the confusion.

Comment: The application doesn't need to be on Facebook to get an app id. You're going to want one for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a long lived access token you have two options:

1. Use the [Client-Side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) process, get a short lived token and then exchange it with using the [new endpoint](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) which was introduced to "replace" the "offline_access" permission which was deprecated.
2. Use the [Server-Side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) process which will result in a long lived access token (60 days).